# Docked Laptop superslow wifi connection when closed

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, speed, pci

I have a Lenovo T440p, which when working at home I dock onto a docking station. There, I have an additional screen connected, so I want to close the laptop when working with the large screen.

However, I'm experiencing some weird behavior when i close the screen of the laptop when docked. When I close the laptop, then initially everything is fine, until suddenly (maybe 20s after closing the lid) the internet speed drops drastically (down to around 1.5 mbps or even nothing at times), watching a youtube video is impossible, emails, webpages don't load, etc. To resolve the issue I have to open the screen of the laptop, then everything reverts back to normal, internet speed is fast again.

I have not found any suitable settings in the power options (maybe closing the lid reduces power to a PCI Bus lane or so where wifi modules are depending on?). My computer knowledge is not good enough to fiddle around with the registry on my own without help. I have a dualboot system with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, there this issue does not occur, FWIW. Would anyone know where to start looking?

Correction: The issue also exists in Ubuntu. So I assume its either a BIOS thing or really just stupid antenna placement in the Hardware?

Comment: Well, the WiFi antenna is inside the lid. Though that doesn’t explain any delay in worsening performance.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the BIOS (and the OS) for a setting that allows the computer to set the wifi into low-power mode (and disable it).
If poorly done, the function takes the closed lid as indicator to go into low-power wifi mode, which will reduce the transmission quality.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hints. There is no setting in the BIOS that releates to low power modes or similar for wireless connections. Also, in the Power Options, the settings for wireless adapter are set to maximum performance. I couldnt find a setting for wireless adapter that links to closing the lid.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is likely hardware related, due to the position of the wireless antennas being around the bezel of the screen on most laptops the signal gets reduced to almost nothing when the computer is closed